# How to document C code in Eclipse (intellisense/javadoc like tooltips)

Tags: c, eclipse, documentation-generation

Is it possible to document C code in Eclipse (3.4 w/ CDT) in such a way that JavaDoc/Intellisense like documentation is auto generated and displayed?

E.g. On typing a function name followed by a '(' you get the first param with a tooltip explaining the meaning of that parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely where VS shines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge: No (With CDT5.0.2).

The best you have right now is what they are calling: **[content assist](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_content_assist.htm)**

[alt text http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/images/contentAssist_example.png](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/images/contentAssist_example.png)

Comment: Oh well, can't have everything I suppose! 

FWIW, A nightly build of CDT 6.0.0 (I.I200902031437) doesn't appear to add the desired functionality either but it does offer heuristic finding of includes which is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can view this project: http://gna.org/projects/eclox

Eclox is a simple doxygen frontend plug-in for eclipse. It aims to provide a slim and sleek integration of the code documentation process into eclipse.

Features Overview

```
* Graphical edition of doxyfile settings,
* integrated doxygen invokation,
* doxygen outputs logging and
* optional packaged doxygen binaries (for windows and linux).
```

Registration Date: Monday 02/02/2004 at 09:31 CET
License: GNU General Public License V2 or later

Regards

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I have started to use Doxygen to document my code. This allows documenting in a JavaDoc syntax which I really wanted, and Doxygen then parses the source to form various output formats (html/xml/chm etc..) which is working well.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux Tools project started working on such a help facility. Currently it will provide help for Linux system libraries, but there are plans to extend this to e.g. doxygen generated help, too.

For a demo see:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/linuxtools/videos/libhoverdemo.ogg